# getting error as java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

Tags: java, spring-mvc

i am trying to run below code but it is failing with below error. i am not able to find out what has gone wrong. please help.
error :java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 at line number 37.

code :

```
package com.ugam.filter.repository;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

import com.ugam.domain.filter.FilterTemplate;


@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:properties/filterTemplate.properties")
public class FilterTemplateRepository  {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public Map<String,List<FilterTemplate>> getBean()
    {

        Map<String,List<FilterTemplate>> filterTemplateMap=new HashMap<String,List<FilterTemplate>>();
        String moduleName=env.getProperty("module");
        for(String eachmoduleName : moduleName.split(",")){
            String templateName=env.getProperty(eachmoduleName + ".templateNames");
            List<FilterTemplate> filterTemplatelist=new ArrayList<FilterTemplate>();
            for (String eachtemplateNames : templateName.split(",")) {
                String templateNameFields[] = env.getProperty(eachmoduleName + "." + eachtemplateNames).split(",");
                FilterTemplate filterTemplate=new FilterTemplate();
                filterTemplate.setTemplateHtml(templateNameFields[0]);
                filterTemplate.setClassSelect(templateNameFields[1]);
                filterTemplatelist.add(filterTemplate);
            }
            filterTemplateMap.put(eachmoduleName, filterTemplatelist);
        }
        return filterTemplateMap;

    }


    public List<FilterTemplate> getModuleData(String moduleName)
    {

        return getBean().get(moduleName);
    }
}
```

property file :-
    module=dashboard

```
dashboard.templateNames=templateHtml1,templateHtml2,templateHtml3,templateHtml4
dashboard.templateHtml1=dashBoardLeftInsight.html,leftpanel
dashboard.templateHtml2=dcdcsFilterOptions.html.html,
dashboard.templateHtml3=advanceFilterOptions.html,advancedOptions
dashboard.templateHtml4=reportFilterOptions.html,reportdashboard
```

Comment: Show us the property in your property file.

Comment: Are you sure that there is at least one `,` every time you call `env.getProperty(eachmoduleName + "." + eachtemplateNames).split(",");`?  Check your array length before assuming that there are at least 2 elements.

Comment: Yes, templateNameFields[1] implies that the array is at least 2 elements long (i.e., that there is one comma there),

Comment: @SteveCohen How does it imply it? It only implies that OP is expecting 2 elements there, not that they really are there.

Comment: What's in line **number 37**?

Answer (score 2):

Are you convinced that:

```
 env.getProperty(eachmoduleName + "." + eachtemplateNames)
```

contains values with a comma in it? If it does not, then `filterTemplate.setClassSelect(templateNameFields[1]);` will give you your Exception.

EDIT START:

Your data contains `dashboard.templateHtml2=dcdcsFilterOptions.html.html,`

This **does** contain a ',' comma, but the regular [String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) will ignore the empty values after the comma. You may want to use the 'full' version of [String.split(",", -1)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) which will return and empty String value representing the empty value in the input string....

EDIT END:

You need to program more 'defensively', and expect the unexpected:

```
            // add a default value "" if the property is not set.
            String value = env.getProperty(eachmoduleName + "." + eachtemplateNames, "");
            String templateNameFields[] = value.split(",");
            if (templateNameFields.length != 2) {
                 // log an error or something
                 continue; // move on to valid data.
            }
            FilterTemplate filterTemplate=new FilterTemplate();
            filterTemplate.setTemplateHtml(templateNameFields[0]);
            filterTemplate.setClassSelect(templateNameFields[1]);
```

Comment: And in fact, judging by the newly posted property file, this is precisely what is happening for templateHtml2

Comment: Edited to suggest String.split(..., -1)

Answer (score 0):

On this line

```
filterTemplate.setClassSelect(templateNameFields[1]);
```

it fails because this has no "class select".

```
dashboard.templateHtml2=dcdcsFilterOptions.html.html,
```